# Django: Generic View not working

Tags: django

i am following the django tutorial on the web site and i am stuck on using the generic view.

views.py

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Questions
    template_name = 'tolls/detail.html'
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
```

detail.html

```
<h1> {{question.question_text}} </h1>
```

Nothing is displayed in my details.html

If i don't use generic view it works with below function and url

view.py

`def detial(request, question_id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Questions, pk=question_id)
        return render(request, 'tolls/detail.html', {'question': question})`

urls.py

```
`url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detial, name='detail'),`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default name for accessing your model instance is `object`. So either use `{{ object.question_text }}` in your template or specify a name in your view class using `context_object_name`:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Questions
    template_name = 'tolls/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'question'
```